# What am I doing wrong with this htacess redirect on two wordpress sites?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I was hosting two versions of wordpress sites in two languages.
http://ru.website.com
and
http://website.com

Now I copied http://ru.website.com to http://www.website.com/ru

And I want a redirect that would redirect any urls or links from http://ru.website.com/link automatically to http://www.website.com/ru/link

I created the following htacess and placed it at root of ru.website.com

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ru.website.net$ RewriteRule (.*)$`

`https://www.website.net/ru/$1 [R=301,L]`

But it doesn't work. No redirect happens.

What is wrong with this htaccess code? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Your examples use ru.website.COM (emphasis mine) but your rewrite rules work with ru.website.NET -- is that a typo? Or the source of the problem? :)

Comment: yeah a typo sorry

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ru.website.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^ https://www.website.com/ru/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

(NOTE: not sure if you want ".com" or ".net" so adjust accordingly...)